# FadeIn() div in function Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

sorry for the question but i have problem with FadeIn() (and so with Jquery):

I have:

```
<div style="height:50px;width:700px">
  <div id="Ipo" style="width: 100px;display:block; float: left; text-align:center; background-color:#ff0000; margin-left: 20%">
    <input id="ipo" type="radio" name="eq" />       
  </div>
  <div id="Time" style="width: 100px;display:block; float: left; text-align:center; background-color:#ffff00; margin-left: 31%">
    <input id="time" type="radio" name="eq" />
  </div>
```

with a form, i start a function in javascript, and in this function i would like to put this code:

```
 $('#Ipo').hide().fadeIn(5000);
 $('#Time').hide().fadeIn(5000);
```

but doesn't work :(

Thanks

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/t7gs7Lny/8/)

Comment: what does not work, what is the problem? Describe more please.

Comment: Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/pfw94b2e/ - Where do you include `jQuery`?

Comment: Doesn't work, see the example: http://jsfiddle.net/tc5s7uxm/

Comment: Nothing? Please see the jsfiddle :(

Comment: `$('input').click(start);`

Comment: @Owlvark doesn't work :( help me please

Comment: I suggest not relying on jsfiddle and separating all HTML, CSS and Javascript; it will be easier to debug.

Comment: But i don't understand where is the problem, and how your code (in last post) could be an help for me :( really is too difficult this question?

Answer (score 0):

i solved in this way:

This is html dom of buttons:

the first button (it is a button that i said in the first post is for form)

```
<div style="text-align:center">
 <input id="ca" type="radio" onClick="start()"/>
</div>
```

And now the div that contains two div (with two buttons):

```
<div style="height:50px;width:700px">
 <div id="Ipo" style="width: 100px;display:none; float: left; text-align:center; background-color:#ff0000; margin-left: 20%">
  <input id="ipo" type="radio" name="eq" />       
 </div>
 <div id="Time" style="width: 100px;display:none; float: left; text-align:center; background-color:#ffff00; margin-left: 31%">
  <input id="time" type="radio" name="eq" />
 </div>
</div>
```

And now the code:

```
$("#ca").click(start);

function start(){
 $('#Ipo').fadeIn(2000);
 $('#Time').fadeIn(2000);
}
```

In my first post there where two problems:

1) there was **display:block;**

2) i add in the code this line **$("#ca").click(start);**

Bye and thanks for the help ;)